# How to display Parse username in XCode

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

How do I access a registered username in Parse and display it with a label in a ViewController? This does not seem to be working:

```
 self.usernameLabel.text = PFUser.currentUser()?["username"]
```

Comment: did you try just doing `PFUser.currentUser().username?`
What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @Erakk You the real MVP.

Comment: This is not a question about Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
self.usernameLabel.text = PFUser.currentUser().username
```

The `self.usernameLabel.text` wants to be loaded with a `string`. The `PFUser.currentUser()?["username"]` gets a parse `object` containing a `string`. So the problem can be solved by assigning `PFUser.currentUser()?["username"]`to a `var` before loading it to the `self.usernameLabel.text`.

This can be done like this:

```
var username = PFUser.currentUser()?["username"]
self.usernameLabel.text = username
```

But parse gives you a shortcut to some of the basic user information and thats why you can use `PFUser.currentUser().username`to get the username string right away.